# optimal solution for different feasibility sets

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Suppose we have an optimal solution $x^*$ for the convex optimization problem $ \min_x \{f(x) : Cx \leq d\}$ and we know that $x^* \in \{x : Ax=b, Cx\leq d\}$. The function $f(x)$ is a strictly convex quadratic function.

Can we say that $x^*$ is also the optimal solution for $\min_x \{f(x) :Ax=b, Cx \leq d\}$?

Comment: if the feasible set gets smaller, you cannot obtain any lower values than $f(x^*)$, so: yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can, since $Ax=b$ will add nothing but some extra constraints which are already satisfied bu $x^*$.